# Oracle query different performances between prod and staging environment

Tags: performance, explain

So I have those 2 Oracle 12c databases R2, prod and staging environment, both are perfectly aligned and running on identical hardware.
The same select statement will take about 400ms on staging while it will not take less than 4 seconds.

Our expert DBA left the company leaving me and my relatively thin skills to investigate on this. I have no idea how to proceed, although I saw some major differences in each explain plans (1st is prod, 2nd is staging) regarding cardinalities.

[image: PROD EXPLAIN PLAN]

[image: PREPROD EXPLAIN PLAN]

I don't really know where to start to only identify the source of the issue.
I rebuilt the index involved in the query with no effect. I later dropped it and created it again with no more improvment.

Edit:

Following suggestions, I gathered the stats with sample = 100% with no improvment.
Though for some reason the only different parameter between prod and staging was sga_max_size value which was much higher in staging. Aligning it in prod helped me regain similar respond time (query runs in 500ms) though the explain plans are still differents.

I will mark this as resolved as the main performance issue is now gone

Comment: It’s the same plan, just expected to return different rows as your statistics are different. Are the estimates close to reality? Are you really looking up 200k rows by index and then distincting then only to return 50 rows?

Comment: This also suggests you have different data and your query is returning a different number of results. Is it right for the data to be different? I would suggest starting by optimizing how it runs on production

Comment: Is this 12c release 1, or 12c release 2? Please [edit] your question to clarify.  Release 2 has a lot of goodies in it..

Answer (score 0):

Ditto what Andrew said in comments to your question.  It might help to gather statistics on the table(s) and indexes at 100% via `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` parameter `estimate_percent=>100` to ensure any edge cases in the data are captured.

I don't remember whether Oracle 12c gathers full statistics when building an index, but either way, if the data in the index is skewed, gathering statistics at 100% would be the first thing to try.  The default is for Oracle to make an educated guess on how much of the table to look at when gathering statistics, in order to determine the plan at execution time.

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-CA6A56B9-0540-45E9-B1D7-D78769B7714C) for that PL/SQL function.

Another thing that might be an issue, but would not likely the issue for your symptoms, is that even though the two servers have "identical hardware" there can be big differences in the network, disk, etc. that Oracle is making the wrong estimates for those pieces.  Take a look at the [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-257CDCB8-3595-464B-8337-43EF23A6068D) and the examples; I've found some big differences on "identical" servers in the actual performance.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions, I gathered the stats with sample = 100% with no improvment. Though for some reason the only different parameter between prod and staging was sga_max_size value which was much higher in staging. Aligning it in prod helped me regain similar respond time (query runs in 500ms) even though the explain plans are still differents.